# $(window).resize function odd behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `mouseenter` event that removes a class from an element, if the statement `$("."+ElementID+"-delta-ui-dropdown-appendHere").attr('style') == 'display: block;'){` is false.

It worked perfectly until I added an event that is triggered by resizing the browser. When initially loaded, the `mouseenter` event works fine, but when I resize the browser, the `mouseenter` event removes the class even when the condition is true.

If I remove the `$(window).resize` code, the `mouseenter` event works again.

```
//this is the code triggered

var getWidth = $("."+ElementID+"-delta-ui-dropdown-appendHere").outerWidth();

$(window).resize(function() {
    // This will execute whenever the window is resized
    if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
        console.log('original');
        $(".delta-ui-dropdown-common-"+ElementID+"").css({width:getWidth});
    } else {
        var inputGroupWidth = $(".delta-ui-dropdown-"+ElementID+"").width();
        $(".delta-ui-dropdown-common-"+ElementID+"").css({width:inputGroupWidth});
        console.log('fit');
    }
});



//this code removes the class even though the condition is true

$('.delta-ui-dropdown-icon-'+ElementID).mouseenter(function() {
    if ($("."+ElementID+"-delta-ui-dropdown-appendHere").attr('style') == 'display: block;') {

    } else {
        $('.delta-ui-dropdown-icon-'+ElementID).removeClass('focus');
    }   
});
```

Comment: You use strange way to check display is block...
You can use css('display') to get it value. 
Or you can use :visible/:hidden selector to find out weather it is visible/hidden.

Comment: @AntonM. sorry sir.., gonna change my code now. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `if` condition will always be `false`. Try to use `css` instead as below:

```
$('.delta-ui-dropdown-icon-'+ElementID).mouseenter(function() {
    if($("."+ElementID+"-delta-ui-dropdown-appendHere").css('display') == "block") {

    } else {
        $('.delta-ui-dropdown-icon-'+ElementID).removeClass('focus');
    }   
});
```

Comment: thanks fixed my problem..  the problem is the mouseenter condition... you're a great help.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)